# Can't parse nested elements

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

I have this XML that I am parsing and for some reason when I try to pull out the "routes" values, I am only getting the first one in the list.  So basically I can extract the "1" value but the rest are being skipped/ignored.  I think it's something to do with the nested elements being so far "down" the list but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any ideas how I can pull out all the route values and not just the first one in the list?

```
<information xmlns="http://testnamespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-      instance">
<errorcode>0</errorcode>
<errormessage/>
<numberofresults>1</numberofresults>
<timestamp>12/01/2014 17:20:04</timestamp>
<results>
   <result>
   <id>1234</id>
   <displayid>1234</displayid>
   <name>A Road</name>
   <name2>Another Road</name2>
     <element1>
       <element2>
         <name>abc</name>
        <routes>
          <route>1</route>
          <route>2</route>
          <route>3</route>
          <route>4</route>
          <route>5</route>
          <route>6</route>
        </routes>
       </element2>
     </element1>
</result>
</results>
</information>
```

This is my code:

```
foreach (var routeInfo in StopInfo.Descendants(ns + "routes"))
{
    string route = routeInfo.Element(ns + "route").Value;
    lstResults.Items.Add(route);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting only single route element of `routes` (and it will be first element with value `1`):

```
routeInfo.Element(ns + "route")
```

And you do same thing for each `routes` element in you xml. So, if you have only one `routes` element in your xml, you'll end with single value `1` added to listbox. What you need is getting `route` elements of selected `routes` element (they are direct children, so simple `Elements()` will do the job):

```
foreach (var route in StopInfo.Descendants(ns + "routes").Elements())
    lstResults.Items.Add((string)route);
```

Also keep in mind that you can simply cast `XElement` to string and some other types to get their value. That will allow to avoid exception if element is not found and you are trying to read its value.

Comment: Thanks, that's working.  but is there a way to pull each value out separately?  When I add them to the listbox its just adding 123456 as one string, rather than each on it's own line.

Comment: @irldev code above should add six route items to listbox. You want only first four?

Comment: Sorry, yeah I want all 6 items.  I tried your most recent edit and that works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you need more then one `route` element you should use another loop:

```
foreach (var routeInfo in StopInfo.Descendants(ns + "routes"))
{
    foreach(var route = routeInfo.Elements(ns + "route"))
        lstResults.Items.Add((string)route);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Sergey Berezovskiy has already provided solution but rather we can also use XMLSerializer and annotation for parsing xml in windows phone For reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.100).aspx

This might increse number of classes but this is the best way to parse XML data in Windows Phone